# How to correctly change page extensions sitewide not to loose rankings in google

Tags: redirect, seo, google-search

Moved content from php files to content management system. Changed page extensions from `.php` to without any extension, like: before `some-page.php` after `some-page`

All php pages keep at server, but made redirection in each php file, like `header('Location:'. basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php') );`. I cannot (do not know how to) do it in .htaccess, because in .htaccess is this code

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show-content.php?$1
DirectoryIndex show-content.php?index
```

From google webmasters tools removed previous sitemap and added the new sitemap. See that the new sitemap accepted, but no urls included.

All above I did 3-4 days before. And today see that website dropped down in search results (some pages can not find at all in first pages).

Trying to understand what I did wrong.

Seems the first thing is wrong redirection code. Changed to `header('Location:'. basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php'), true, 301 );`. Is such code ok?

What else I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to do a 301 redirect from the old URL (with the extension) to the new URL (without the extension) as this tells Google the page has moved to a new location and you want all links and other SEO goodness (like rankings) need to be "transferred" to the new URL.

You can do the 301 redirect any way you want so using PHP's `header()` is fine as long as you are redirecting to the right page. Your example should work fine.

Comment: That is all that necessary? No other activities required from me?

Comment: That's it. Naturally make sure your sitemap has the new URLs as that makes Google's life easier but the 301 redirect is the most important part. Without it you're starting from scratch.